# Using Mask then applying Pathfinder minus front

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, pathfinder

I used mask to create a shape I want.  Now I want to apply minus front (I will put a new shape on top of the masked shape), but it's not working properly.  How to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi. What are you actually masking?  A raster image or vectors?  Boolean operations won't work on raster images. Can you share a screenshot showing what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply (bake in/expand) the mask first. Or, use Pathfinder and **then** apply a clipping mask to the resulting shape.

<sub>(...and, just in case... Pathfinder won't work on linked or embedded raster images)</sub>

That's the best I can offer without seeing the objects you are working with.